# How well do dwarf tomatoes do with dry farming?

Tags: tomatoes

I'm interested in trying to dry farming tomatoes in Western Washington, zone 8. We have got dry summers here.

I will probably try some dwarf varieties anyway, but am curious if anyone has thoughts. Are the root systems stunted, and thus have a harder time reaching deeper groundwater? Or will the lack of foliage help them minimize water requirements, and let them do better?

And, any recommendations for an indeterminate dwarf variety that would work well with dry farming?

Comment: Your zone information just can not be correct; 5 or 6 along the coast...3-4 inland.  Not at all sure what you mean by dry farming tomatoes.  If anything if one grows tomatoes they will know how to BABY them...ventilation, pruning, proper pH, proper watering amounts and drainage, planting them where other tomatoes/potatoes/peppers have never been planted, fertilizer low in Nitrogen...on and on...my goodness.  To imagine tomatoes or any plants other than TREES to reach and use water from the water table is RIDICULOUS.  Where in Western Washington are you talking about?  Rainshadow or marine?

Comment: It is counter-intuitive, but tomatoes can indeed be farmed without irrigation: http://modernfarmer.com/2014/07/well-runs-dry-try-dry-farming/

I am indeed in zone 8. Quite a bit of Western Washington is, actually: http://www.plantmaps.com/interactive-washington-2012-usda-plant-zone-hardiness-map.php